# Datatable search box value updating with custom search box value

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am adding custom search box which will search in one column(Name) only.

[image]

The problem is when I write something in top column, default search box value is also updating.

Here is my code below:

```
let oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable();
$('#nameTextField').keyup(function () { // nameTextField is custom input box id
    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
})
```

I don't want to update default search box value. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Post your HTML as well please, I need to see it's structure to see where's your problem coming from

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$('#nameTextField').keyup(function () { // nameTextField is custom input box id
    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
})
```

with

```
$('#nameTextField').on('keyup', function () 
{
   oTable.column(1).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

here  `oTable.column(1)` points to second column of table i.e. "Name" only and ignoring other columns.

[example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bck6qt3r/)